# TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes and property

Tags: c#, attributes, typedescriptor

Is something like this possible?

There is a class with the [DataContract] attribute. This class has two properties, one is int and the other is string. There are two different instances of this class.

Is it possible to assign dynamically the [DataMember] attribute only to the int property of the first instance and only to the string property of the second instance? If so, would you mind providing a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not assign attributes in run time without doing pretty complex magick with dynamic class generation.

Okay, I dont understand `TypeDescriptor`:)
So, in general you need to create own ICustomTypeDescriptor and implement GetProperties method to return PropertyDescriptor's ([following constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w8xkftdb.aspx)) expanding attribute array.

```
static Attribute[] AddAttribute(Attribute[] attributes, Attribute attr) {
    Array.Resize(ref attributes, attributes.Length + 1);
    attributes[attributes.Length - 1] = new attr;
    return attributes;
}

public MyPropertyDescriptor(MemberDescriptor propDef)
       : base(propDef, AddAttribute(propDef.Attributes, new DataMembeAttribute()))
```

Comment: You dont understand `TypeDescriptor`.